# Angular passing props to child not updating

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass an object down to a child component as a prop. The object starts as null and gets set when a user selects an item from the list. What's strange is that the object gets set correct the first time but not after.

Here is my parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <search-bar (submitted)="onSearch($event)"></search-bar>
    <div>
      <video-detail [video]="selectedVideo"></video-detail>
      <video-list [videos]="videos" [onVideoSelect]="onVideoSelect" ></video-list> 
    <div>  
  </div>
`
})     
export default class AppComponent {
  videos = [];
  selectedVideo = null;

  constructor(private youtube: YoutubeService) { }

  onSearch(searchTerm: string) {
    this.youtube.search(searchTerm).subscribe((response) => {
      this.videos = response.items;
      this.selectedVideo = response.items[0];
    });

  }

  // called when the user clicks an item
  onVideoSelect(video: object) {
    this.selectedVideo = video;
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
const { Component, Input } = ng.core;
const { DomSanitizer } = ng.platformBrowser;

@Component({
  selector: 'video-detail',
  template: 
  `
    <ng-container *ngIf="video; else loading">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <iframe title="video player" [src]="getVideoSrc()"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4 [innerHTML]="video.snippet.title"></h4>
                    <p [innerHTML]="video.snippet.description"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
   <ng-template #loading>
     <div>
       No Video Selected.
     </div>
   </ng-template>
  `
})
export default class VideoDetailComponent { 
    @Input() video = null;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  getVideoSrc() {
    const videoSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${this.video?.id?.videoId}`);
    return videoSrc;
  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass objects as `@Inputs()` into children, Angular only begins change detection when the object *reference* has changed.

Therefore when you update the object, it needs to be a new reference in order for your child component to act on it.

Try using

```
this.selectedVideo = Object.assign({}, response.items[0]);
```

This will create a new object each time so angular will pick up the change.

Comment: Ahhh thanks! I didn't realize. Assuming I can use spread syntax as well?

Comment: I believe you can! Anything that changes the object reference. Spread operator is probably even more elegant.

Comment: Ok I tried that but it still does not seem to be working

Comment: You've accepted the answer. I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: yeah sorry. You can probably guess from the code it is an app using the Youtube API and I had gone over my usage quota so I couldn't test your answer. Anyways, long story short, the value does not get updated with your solution. If I do a console log in onVideoSelect after assigning the new value with this.selectedVideo = {...video}; then then selected video has the correct new value but not in the VideoDetail component

Comment: Does it work with the Object.assign() method?

Comment: The issue was that I was losing my 'this' context when passing the function down to the child component. solution was to use either an Output with event emitter or bind the context of this when passing the function down. It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new object and pass as `@Input` so that the angular can identify the change.

Try

```
onSearch(searchTerm: string) {
    this.youtube.search(searchTerm).subscribe((response) => {
      this.videos = response.items;
      this.selectedVideo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.items[0]));  // <-- here
    });

  }
```